# complexity of printing string permutations

Tags: java, string, permutation

Here is my code to print string permutations. I am struggling to calculate time complexity of the functions. Can someone please suggest few pointers.  And if there is any more time efficient method ?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Permutations {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String> aList = permutation("ABCC");
        for(int i=0; i<aList.size(); i++){
            System.out.print(aList.get(i) + " ");
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> permutation(String s) {
        // The result
        ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
        // If input string's length is 1, return {s}
        if (s.length() == 1) {
            res.add(s);
        } else if (s.length() > 1) {
            int lastIndex = s.length() - 1;
            // Find out the last character
            String last = s.substring(lastIndex);
            // Rest of the string
            String rest = s.substring(0, lastIndex);
            // Perform permutation on the rest string and
            // merge with the last character
            res = merge(permutation(rest), last);
        }
        return res;
    }


    public static ArrayList<String> merge(ArrayList<String> list, String c) {
        ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
        // Loop through all the string in the list
        for (String s : list) {
            // For each string, insert the last character to all possible postions
            // and add them to the new list
            for (int i = 0; i <= s.length(); ++i) {
                String ps = new StringBuffer(s).insert(i, c).toString();
                res.add(ps);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh, looks recursive - `merge(permutation(rest), last)`.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils that's why I hate recursion, it always happens in one little line. My mistake.

Comment: it should be n^2, since you have a nested for loop in 'merge'

Comment: @Sam It won't be as simple as that

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc it is, you just need to consider worst-case

Comment: If you are printing all the permutations of a string, it will be at least n! number of prints (assuming n distinct elements in the string).

Comment: Look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For speed improvements, a `LinkedList` would be faster, also using the same `StringBuffer` and `StringBuffer#setCharAt(int, char)`. Something like this maybe:

```
List<String> permutations = new ArrayList<String>(initial size); // initial size to avoid multiple arrays to be created
if (s.length() == 1) {
    permutations.add(s);
} else {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s);
    loop { // some kind of loop
        sb.setCharAt(0, 'a'); // do the next permutation
        permutations.add(sb.toString());
    }
}
return permutations;
```

Comment: LinkedList is faster only and only if you are using #delete operation. Try it yourself and look the implementation of LinkedList to know why.

Comment: Hmm, still better than building multiple arrays, could also set an initial size for the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Plain `merge()` is O(n^2). With recurrence it seems to be O(n^3)